# Automate Redis Cluster Creation

Tags: redis

I am working on creating a shell script to automate setup of redis cluster. But I am getting stuck at the create cluster command.

When my script is executing the command

redis-cli --cluster create

It asks to type a yes, but I want to make it non interactive & it should proceed with me giving an input.

I have tried:

yes | redis-cli --cluster create

But this is also not working.

Please help. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: using echo yes | redis-cli --cluster create solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


cmd = 'redis-cli --cluster create 172.31.104.226:6379 172.31.103.167:6379 172.31.102.56:6379 --cluster-replicas 0'
p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
grep_stdout = p.communicate(input='yes\n'.encode())[0]
print(grep_stdout)
```

Comment: why creating a python script to call a redis-cli to grab the output and display it? why not using a bash script?

Comment: I'm writing some redis-cluster automation in python, its just what I prefer :)

see example https://github.com/omnivector-solutions/layer-redis/blob/add_redis_cluster/src/reactive/redis.py